# Multiply hours difference between startdate = 00:00:00 and enddate HH:mm:ss on Float value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need calculate power usage, and it is calculated as the average power per hour multiplied by the number of hours worked per day. Can i multiply value on hours datediff between two datetime, start datetime is always have hour 00, and enddate is system datetime. I tried this code, but it didnt helped me.

```
SELECT @APower24Cell = AVG((CAST(ACurrent24Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(AVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 ,
@BPower24Cell =  AVG((CAST(BCurrent24Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(BVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 ,
@CPower24Cell =  AVG((CAST(CCurrent24Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(CVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 ,
@APower35Cell =  AVG((CAST(ACurrent35Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(AVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 ,
@BPower35Cell =  AVG((CAST(BCurrent35Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(BVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 ,
@CPower35Cell =  AVG((CAST(CCurrent35Cell as FLOAT)*CAST(CVoltage3Sec as FLOAT))/10)/1000 
FROM Energomonitoring 
WHERE TS >= DATEADD(HOUR,-24,GETDATE()) GROUP BY TS

SET @FULLPOWER = (@APower24Cell+@BPower24Cell+@CPower24Cell+@APower35Cell+@BPower35Cell+@CPower35Cell) * DATEDIFF(hour, dateadd(hour, datepart(hour,GETDATE()),CAST(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),112) as datetime)), GETDATE())
```

Comment: some sample data and expected result will be good

Comment: Do you need to deal with fractional hours?

Comment: In the final SET, you do some kind of hour calculation. Whatever it is supposed to do, it is incorrect, because it will always return 0. When using DATEDIFF(hour,..), you are counting hour boundaries. It will not give you fractional hours. If you need fractional hours, then I suggest you calculate the difference (of the final hour) in seconds, cast it to decimal (or float) and divide it by 3600.